# Does Google+ API have any hourly rate limit?

Tags: java, api, google-plus

I know there are quotas there: https://code.google.com/apis/console
But these are daily quotas. And there I see 10,000 queries per day (Courtesy Limit).
Actually my program makes 170-190 requests per hour after that receives such response from Google+ API:

```
{
"code" : 403,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "usageLimits",
"message" : "Rate Limit Exceeded",
"reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
} ],
"message" : "Rate Limit Exceeded"
}
```

After 1 hour program does 170-190 again till get same error. But 190 requests per hour * 24 hours is far from 10,000.

I am using method people.search and google-api-java-client library version 1.15.0-rc.
Initialize Plus service like below:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(PlusScopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(KEY_FILE))
                .build();
        Plus plus = new Plus.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APP_NAME).build();
```

And use search method like this:

```
Plus.People.Search searchPeople = people.search(fullname);
    searchPeople.setMaxResults(50L);
    searchPeople.setFields("items(id),nextPageToken");
    PeopleFeed peopleFeed = searchPeople.execute();
while (true) {
        if (peopleFeed.getItems().size() == 0) {
            break;
        }

        /* Save people info here */

        if (peopleFeed.getNextPageToken() == null) {
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        searchPeople.setPageToken(peopleFeed.getNextPageToken());
        peopleFeed = searchPeople.execute();
    }
```

I tried to change sleep time to 1 sec or 2 sec - same behaviour.
Tried to regenerate key file - no luck.

Did I do something incorrect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is threefold:

1. The rate limit is both *per day* (10,000) and *per second* (5).
2. The error message is shared between the types.
3. The time until the next window is not provided.

Thus, I have my applications wait `rand(1,5)` seconds and if they are rate limited again, I wait `3600` seconds before retrying.

Comment: I have finished with similar solution - little wait between requests and big wait if catch rate limit. It seems like there are no better solutions so far.

Comment: Then why they offer batch request then? I got rate limited every time I do batch request.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the `Quotas` link at the API Console you indicated, it will break down the daily limit for your app's usage of each API, but will also list a per-user quota. For example, mine currently shows

```
     Google+ API    5.0 requests/second/user
```

In general, their API endpoint may allow bursts more than this, and this should be considered an estimate, but going over this limit for extended durations may cause the rate limit exceeded error you see.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Yes, mine shows 5.0 requests/second/user too. But I'm using wait periods (_Thread.sleep()_) to stay inside this rate. And currently I am the only user of this app.